# Is an association list in LISP the same thing as a Dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, lisp, common-lisp

I am reading a book about Common LISP and the author says : "An alist consists of key/value pairs stored in a list."

So it made me think, is this the same thing as a Dictionnary in C# or not?
If so why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a distinction between abstract concepts and concrete data-structures.

A dictionary is an abstract concept - a mapping of keys to values. It can be implemented with several different approaches:

- as a list: of key-value pairs (Lisp's alists), a flat list of interleaved keys and values (Lisp's plists), as a pair of two lists of keys and values
- as a table, be it Lisp's hash-table/Java's HashMap or some other kind of table
- as a tree (Java's TreeMap)
- etc

C#'s Dictionary is a data-structure that supports (amortized) constant lookup time, like CL's hash-table. In this regard it is different from alist, that has linear lookup time. Also alists don't depend on element's hash-code in order to store/retrieve it. The API of alists is also different, than Dictionary's. There's `assoc` and `rassoc` to lookup an element from the left side and right side respectively. (So, unlike in a conventional dictionary, there can be multiple mappings of the same key to different values in an alist). Also there are `acons` and `pairlis` to construct an `alist`.

**EDIT** <s>And, finally, there's no standard function to remove an item from alist.</s>
You can delete an element with `(remove key alist :key #'car)`. But note, that this operation leaves the original list intact and returns a modified list as a result.

Comment: Removal from alist is `(remove key alist :key #'car)`.

Answer (score 2):

Comparisons between alists and hash tables (which `Dictionary` uses), since nobody seems to have touched on this yet:

Alists:

- Are simple to implement (just a list of pairs)
- Have linear-time lookup (thus only useful for small lists)

Hash tables:

- Take a little more effort to implement (in particular, you must implement a stable hash function for keys)
- Have amortised constant-time lookup

Answer (score 0):

It's a mapping from keys to values. So it can act similar to a dictionary. During the evolution of Lisp, hash-tables have been added, which serve a similar purpose.

Comment: .NET's `Dictionary` is implemented using a hash table. Thus, it would probably be more useful to touch on the difference between an alist and a hash table. IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are very similar and serve a similar purpose, but there is at least one significant difference:

A .NET `Dictionary` cannot have multiple items with the same key!

Apparently, [an alist can](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html):

> When searching an association list for an association with a given key, the first one found is returned, if there is more than one.

Comment: can. but does not need to. Usually the lists are destructive and it is easy to replace an existing value.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, its pretty much the same thing. Also called associative arrays (perl) and maps (java and others).

Comment: Although Perl programmers tend to call them “hashes,” in general discourse, even though we know they're supposed to be called “associative arrays” on a good day. Just for fun, JavaScript calls the same concept, “Objects.”